# Entityframework 4 query entities dynamically by name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Im using Entity Framework 4 in my app. I have simple set of entities for example:

Orders: Id, Code, Name, StatusId, SectorId

Sectors: Id, Name, Code

Statuses: Id Name, Code

I have to load data to table Orders from xls it has structure like:  Code(Order), Name, Code(sector), Code(status). 
So for foreign keys I have to query for foreign key id by Code (for sectors and statuses) and then asssign to SectorId and StatusId;
I have big tables with dozens of  fields. So I don’t want to set every field manually.
If I know the structure if xls I can create a dictionary Dictionary where key is the name of the field (in Orders table) and value is the index of column in xls.
So id like to have something like

```
foreach(var item in Dictionary)
{

///Determine if the field is Foreign key for Entity Order (for example in ObjectContext) using GetType().GetProperty().GetValue.... or something

// If so query  ObjectContext for the id of the entity that is foreign key using a   value of Code from xls.

}
```

Is it possible to accomplish and how? Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite disappointing that nobody could help me.  The answer was of course Reflections.
As was mentioned in a question we can create a dictionary of entity properties being imported from xls, with property name as a key and xls column index as value.
Then having a List> importData - as imported data in foreach loop through all rows of xls.
Then loop through dictionary and if there is entity property with name matching key just set the values.
There should be some checks. But as an example:

```
MyEntity editItem=new MyEntity();  
foreach (List<string> data in importData) //loop each xls row
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo pr in MyEntity.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        int excelindex = -1;
            if (excelFields.Keys.Contains(pr.Name))
            {
            excelFields.TryGetValue(pr.Name, out excelindex);
            editItem.GetType().GetProperty(pr.Name).SetValue(editItem, Convert.ChangeType(data[excelindex], editItem.GetType).GetProperty(pr.Name).PropertyType), null);
        }
    }
}
```

This stuff is more compact then hundreds of fields initiated one by one, there is some reuse also. Because for different entities you only have to generate new dictionaries, while the main function is the same.